# Request type not being set in non gui mode in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am running a test in jmeter, when I run it in GUI mode, it runs absolutely fine, but when I run it in non GUI mode then the HTTP request type is not being set. The HTTP request type should be either GET or POST depending on the sampler configuration but its coming out as null and as a result the response is also blank.

I run my tests in non GUI mode with the following command

```
jmeter -n -p user.properties -t submission_test/submission_test.jmx -l submission_test/results.jtl
```

Can anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong in this.

**Update** Adding more information
Below is screen shot of one of the sampler

[image: Sampler Request]

This the Sampler Request according to the logs

```
Thread Name: Thread Group 1-2
Sample Start: 2014-02-19 11:25:45 IST
Load time: 349
Latency: 136
Size in bytes: 47330
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 0
Response code: 200
Response message: OK

Response headers:


HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null
```

This is the actual request

```
null http://www.hackerearth.com/load-testing/

[no cookies]

Request Headers:
```

Ideally cookies should have been set in this as I am using a HTTP Cookie Manager.
The Response Data tab contains nothing.

This is what the log looks like http://pastebin.com/4hDx4rFe

HTTP Request Default config is

[image: HTTP Request Default]

**Solution:**
The problem was occurring because my version of jmeter was 2.3.4 where as the latest version is 2.11. I had installed jmeter using `apt-get install` so if you are facing the same issue then the problem will be resolved if you upgrade.

Comment: Could you show your test plan and particularly the request failing ? also could you share jmeter.log content ?

Comment: I have added more information in the question. Apparently the request parameters are not being set in the non GUI mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version is something like 8 years old.

Use JMeter 2.11 and if you still have issues, show Http Request Default configuration.

Comment: My JMeter version is 2.3.4, I guess that's the latest version. I have embedded a screen shot that gives HTTP Request Default config

Comment: Last version is http://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html 2.11. I still see your screenshot showing version 2.3.4. Download last version from Website,if possible share your jmx file and jmeter.log for help. Otherwise I won't be able to help you

Comment: I have shared the log here is the link for that http://pastebin.com/4hDx4rFe and the jmx file is here http://pastebin.com/Cpvbj675

Comment: I tested your test plan in NON GUI mode with 2.11 and HOST set to  localhost with mirror server and it works fine. So first try with 2.11 and attach jmeter.log showing you use 2.11 (current one shows 2.11), then if you still have failure, I will have a further look.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for the help, I installed 2.11 and the test is running fine in the non GUI mode. Previously i had installed jmeter using sudo apt-get install jmeter. Failed to understand from where did it install 2.3.4. Once again thanks for the help